# How do we change the digital encoding method of a signal? (eg. From Unipolar NRZ to Polar NRZ)

Tags: microcontroller, digital-communications, encoding

We have different digital encoding methods like Unipolar, Polar, Bipolar, Manchester. I was working with stm32f411re and I saw USART uses Unipolar NRZ. So how do we change this encoding methods?

I searched in the internet but couldn't find any relevant information about my question.

So finally I asked Chatgpt & Bard, they consistently quoted "data format registers" and "transmission control registers". But I'm unable to find these registers in any MCU.

Comment: You can't find those registers because your MCU only supports Unipolar NRZ. That's all a standard UART supports. If you want something else, then you'll need to specifically look for that feature in an MCU when you choose it.

Comment: the MCU manufacturer can easily use a different name for the register

Comment: This is a nice illustration of why ChatGPT as it currently is is basically useless for serious engineering: it can't tell you what it's freely made up from what is compiled facts from other sources.

Answer (score 0):

Standard usarts use unipolar NRZ. You need different peripherals to generate the other signal encodings, though depending on the bit rate, you might be able to bit-bang what you need.

Answer (score 0):

UARTs uses NRZ with digital logic levels  and are unipolar. Add an offset, or remove it, and it's bipolar. RS-232 is a common bipolar NRZ method for UART, just add an RS-232 transceiver chip.

Other interfaces use other codings.